# C++ threads - non-shared members

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcpclient

I have Client class:

```
class Client
{
    std::vector<char> buffer;

    //actually these are asio socket and waitable_timer but that's beside the point
    Socket socket;
    Timer timer;

    public:
    void send_request(std::string req); //sends request in new thread and immediately returns
};
```

If I'm not mistaken, *buffer*, *socket* and *timer* are shared among threads. Now I want *socket* and *buffer* shared between threads so they share connection and read into same buffer. But I want each thread to have it's own *timer*. Is there a better way to do so than creating timer locally in *send_request(std::string)* function and then pass it via arguments to other functions (functions called by *send_request*)? Note, I could possibly create new timer in each function and then destroy it at the end (since each function sets deadline, reads data and calls another function which sets new deadline independent of previous one) but with asio I couldn't get it running after couple hours nor has I seen it used this way so consider this not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::mutex`.
`<mutex_obj>.lock()` to lock the objects, and `<mutex_obj>.unlock` to unlock them.

Comment: I don't quite follow how this is gonna help me. I can use mutex to guard shared objects but the question is whether it's possible to have some member shared between threads and some not.

Comment: Re, "whether it's possible to have some member shared between threads and some not." A variable is "shared" if more than one thread accesses it, and it is not shared if only one thread accesses it. So, what you're asking is, is it possible to write a program were a certain variable is only ever accessed by one thread? Yes. That's possible.

Comment: @user680891 so set the socket and the buffer to be static.

Comment: And also write `class Client`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a single instance of `Client` or `Connection` class with the `socket` and `buffer` fields, and multiple instances of a `Session` class (with the `timer` field) linked to a `Connection` instance.

By the way I'm not sure how do you meaningfully share a single socket and a buffer between multiple threads.